# Proving combinatorial formula by induction and combinatorially

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

I need to prove this equation by induction and by combinatorial explanation. $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \begin{array}{c} 4n \\ 4k \end{array} \right) = 2^{4n-2} + (-1)^n \cdot 2^{2n-1}$$

My induction proof:

Base case: p(1): $$\left( \begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 4 \end{array} \right) = 2^{4*1-2} + (-1)^1 \cdot 2^{2*1-1}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\checkmark$$

Inductive step: $p(k) \Longrightarrow p(k+1)$: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \begin{array}{c} 4n \\ 4k \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{c} 4(n+1) \\ 4k \end{array} \right) = 2^{4n-2} + (-1)^n \cdot 2^{2n-1} + \left( \begin{array}{c} 4(n+1) \\ 4k \end{array} \right) \\ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \begin{array}{c} 4(n+1) \\ 4(k+1) \end{array} \right) = 2^{4n-2} + (-1)^n \cdot 2^{2n-1} + \left( \begin{array}{c} 4(n+1) \\ 4k \end{array} \right)$$

I got stuck in this part and I can't find a combinatorial explanation to prove this.

Comment: Hint: By the binomial theorem, $$(x+1)^{4n} + (x-1)^{4n} + (x+i)^{4n} + (x-i)^{4n} = \ldots$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I'm sorry, but I got stuck in this part: $2^{4n} x^k (1 + (-1)^{4n-k} + i^{4n-k} + (-i)^{4n-k})$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have a factor of $2^{4n}$ at this point (it looks like an error), but... you can try a few exponents:  $$1 + (-1)^1 + i^1+(-i)^1=? \\ 1+(-1)^2+i^2+(-i)^2=? \\ 1 + (-1)^3 + i^3+(-i)^3=? \\ 1 + (-1)^4 + i^4+(-i)^4=?$$ You might be able to generalize at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the $n+1$ case isn't actually obtained from the $n$ case by adding an extra term to the end, the way you're thinking of it.

Here are the first few cases of this formula:

- For $n=1$, $\binom 40 + \binom 44 = 2^2 - 2^1$.
- For $n=2$, $\binom 80 + \binom 84 + \binom 88 = 2^6 + 2^3$.
- For $n=3$, $\binom{12}0 + \binom{12}{4} + \binom{12}{8} + \binom{12}{12} = 2^{10} - 2^5$.
- For $n=4$, $\binom{16}{0} + \binom{16}{4} + \binom{16}{8} + \binom{16}{12} + \binom{16}{16} = 2^{14} + 2^7$.

To prove this by induction, you might use Pascal's formula: $\binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$. But then you have to look at some intermediate cases as well: sums where the tops and/or the bottoms of the binomial coefficients aren't multiples of $4$. It's possible to get there, but the binomial theorem argument suggested in the comments is easier.